# Call stylesheet for screen size without compromising normal screen sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I've been looking through quite a few threads/questions on here but can't find exactly what I'm looking for.

Essentially I have done a normal website (with the content sitting within a 960px block so it fits within iPads etc perfectly) which is great but I now need a stylesheet to be used if the screen size is smaller than 480px (for mobile devices).

The problem I'm having seems to be with the meta viewport etc, so I've tried a few different methods such as "`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/dervans/css/mobile.css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" />`" within the header with "`<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>`" set and it works but it breaks the website on iPads and other mobile devices which are larger than 480px in width. If I remove the viewport it works fine again on iPad etc but doesn't pull through the mobile css.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Just add to your css file next strokes:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    class or id{
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Warren. I had tried this originally but it didn't work unless I used the viewport meta in the head which then broke the site on iPads etc. Any ideas?

Comment: i can assume that your viewport settings were incorrect, can you show an example of your viewport code ?

Comment: ok, if i'm getting your problem right, you don't want it to be scaled on ipads, so try to use viewport like that <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" >

Comment: The viewport is `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` with `<meta charset="utf-8">` underneath.

Comment: It still works in terms of pulling through the mobile stylesheet but on my iPad the portrait version cuts off like a third of the screen from the right hand side. Without the viewport it fits perfectly but doesn't pull through the mobile css haha.

Comment: you can also use something like that:`<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:portrait)" href="portrait.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:landscape)" href="landscape.css">`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options available.

The one I would go with is media queries as answered expertly by Warren Grimskin e.g

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.head{
    color: #000000;
}
```

}

Or you could link to separate files in the head section of your html file as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainstyle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobilestyle.css">
```

Styles present in the latter css file would overwrite styles in the former

Also the viewport meta should look something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" />
```